# Pass dynamic parameters in to jquery api call

Tags: jquery, api

Sorry if I simply can not search this correctly...

I am trying to use a value returned from an aJax/json  function.  I need to use thos value in the parameters of the API call.  I can do it when it is simply one value, but when the comma is in there I can not get it to work.

The return is this:

```
{
    "rawUpdates": [{
        "id": "#qty-8007-224",
        "api": "css",
        "params": "'background-color','red'"
    }]
}
```

This is the function I am using (which works when doing single param i.e. html and the value):

```
function parseRawUpdates(call) {
    $.each(call, function(key,json) {
        $(json.id)[json.api](json.params);  
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function parseRawUpdates(call) {
    $.each(call, function(key,json) {
        var params=[],tparams=json.params.split(",");
        for(var k=0;k<tparams.length;k++){
          params[k]=tparams[k].replace(/^'/,"").replace(/'$/,"");
        }
        $.fn.[json.api].apply($(json.id),(params));
    });
}
```

I couldn't come up with a more elegant solution for stripping the parts of json.params of start/end quotes. (Read more about Function.apply [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply))